# How to get out of a Work Out Funk?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, overtraining

Currently I've been working out about 4-5 days a week trying to get in about 6-7 different lifts in per day.  Focusing on a major muscle group each day for example Legs day 1, Arms day 2, chest day 3 etc.  Recently I've been struggling to get through the work outs and getting in only about 4 different lifts.  Is there any suggestions on how to rejuvenate my workouts so that I am able to get back through all my sets.

Comment: Have your eating habits changed? Are you getting less sleep lately? This information would be very helpful for you to get a helpful answer.

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/2999/3778 could also be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have stumbled with your sleep, eating, stress levels, amount of sunlight or socialization, or fallen into overtraining in a million other ways. Maybe your program simply has too much volume for you.

Regardless, it sounds like you're overtrained. Take a day or a week off, and when you start up again, consider doing dramatically less. Five days a week of lifting is often taxing. Sometimes more rest coupled with more intense lifting on the days when you do work out is easier on your recovery in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

What are your goals?  Do you have any goals?  Goals should be a major part of any workout plan.  Whether you want to be a world class athlete, compete well in a local event, improve stamina, lose some weight or maintain an energy level the lack of a goal can make working out a mental challenge.

If you have an athletic induced goal and you're stuttering to workout, post your goals somewhere to jump start you, be in on the inside of your bedroom door, your desk at work/school or in the car.  If you do not have any try to find additional motivation to work out.

Comment: I've got my daily work out goals set for example I want to do these 7 things at this weight.  I get about half way through and just hit that wall.  Before I could get all 7 in no problem.